# how to make an ItemsSource not in use?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a DataGrid in WPF (a class that extends DataGrid), and I would like to edit the items in it. But of course I am getting the following error:

```
Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. 
Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.
```

I have tried changing the itemsSource of the DataGrid, and then adding the items, but I still get the same error. Something like:

```
public class MyDG:DataGrid{

    public void add(){
        List<TimesheetRecord> records = new List<TimesheetRecord>();

        foreach(TimesheetRecord rec in this.Items){
            records.Add(rec);
        }

        //DO SOME STUFF, ADD MORE ITEMS TO records

        ItemCollection col = this.Items;
        this.ItemsSource = records;
        col.Clear();

       foreach(TimesheetRecord rec in records){
            col.add(red);//exception thrown here
        }

        this.ItemsSource = col;
    }

}
```

I don't understand why I am getting that error, when I have already changed the itemsSource to a different list...?

I can't (easily) add the items to the list which is originally bound as the itemsSource, because that list exists in a different class. Would it be best for me to just have a global variable in the MyDG class that is `List<TimesheetRecord> myItems = new List<TimesheetRecord>();` and then in the constructor for MyDG go `this.ItemsSource = myItems`

Or do you have any other suggestions how I should go about doing this? I am open to anything, as this is the first time I have used databinding, so I am probably doing something wrong...

Comment: where does the error occur? what comes in mind is that you cannot access `this.Items` as the items are dynamically generated but you have to store the source instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decalre records collection as:

```
ObservableCollection<TimesheetRecord> records = new ObservableCollection<TimesheetRecord>();
```

and keep it data-bound to the DataGrid. Manipulate records collection as needed, data binding will take care of keeping UI in sync with the collection.

Comment: So you mean I should just have a global variable in MyDG, ObservableCollection<TimesheetRecord> records, and just add items to that?

Comment: Yes, I think  - based on the code snippet you posted it should work.

Comment: Ok, just changed everything over to do it this way! Seems to be working perfectly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to choose whether to use *Items* or *ItemsSource*, you can't use both interchangably.  Attempting to modify *Items* while using *ItemsSource* assumes an implicit conversion that isn't supported, hence the error.

In this case, it seems like the best approach might be to just set *Items* and add to that collection directly.  To use *ItemsSource*, you'd need to, exactly as you wrote, pass a reference to the *ItemsSource* collection (*List<TimesheetRecord>*) in to your *DataGrid* class.

Comment: What do you mean by "Set Items and add to that collection directly"? You mean that I should never, anywhere in my code use the word "ItemsSource", and instead of adding to the List<TimesheetRecord> in my other class, I should just add/remove to myDataGrid.Items?

Comment: @Toadums yes exactly, that is a possibility.  The problem with doing it that way is that you lose some typing; to access an existing item in the collection, you'd need to cast it to *TimesheetRecord*.  I'd strongly consider using Volma's suggestion, as that preserves the type of the source collection.

Comment: Darn, I just got it working the way you suggested! :( So as per volma's answer, I would make a global list in my MyDG class, and assign that as the itemsSource and add/remove items to that list (observableCollection). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Once you assign "records" to the ItemsSource, you've already updated your collection.  There's no need to manually add items to the dataGrid.Items collection.